# Ubuntu battery performance is very low and more heating?

Tags: backup, power-management, battery, overheating

I am new to the linux world. I recently installed ubuntu 16.04.1 in my Lenovo Yoga 500 laptop. Now my laptop's battery backup become very low. it only give me 1.5 hours to 2 hours backup. In windows 10 it gives me almost 4 hours backup. And I am facing heating problem also.
I'd tried to install powertop but unable to use this getting some error

> powertop: error while loading shared libraries: libpci.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Battery 82% and time remaining 1:52

[image]

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Consider using `tlp`.